# DataDirectory sqlconnection for winForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i'm doing the login form with signup 
my sqlConnection for  asp.net works and i tried to use the same sqlconnection for c# winform but the problem is i can't save data to it 
it will somehow save somewhere it is like flouting .. but the data's not saved to database.. but after i sign up and click save it's working and when i login the data was found and successfully login .. but when i checked the database the data is not saved so it's flouting 
then after i changed the sqlconnection and removed the datadirectory and typed the full path of database it works fine 
but i don't like that.. i want my application to run where ever the user save it 
here's my previous code
this is the one that's not working

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MainDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

here's the one that's working

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Seach ENGINE (June 22, 2015)\SE\SE\MainDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

Answer (score 0):

as we know asp run on Server and windows form run on local computer so in asp you can use .\SQLEXPRESS; but on local computer some time **.\SQLEXPRESS;** not work you need to give full path of your server like **server ip:SqlPort\SQLEXPRESS;**

Comment: do you think i can use localhost\SQLEXPRESS?

Comment: @kaizoshi why you can't use ?

Comment: @kaizoshi if you running asp on your local computer then in asp use .\SQLEXPRESS and in winform use YourCompurUserName\SQLEXPRESS it will work

Comment: i want it to be stand alone.. so i can use it on any computer